# Excel data validation conditional on another cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Here's the context:

```
Sheet 1 : 
A1 = "50255"
A2 = "Soccer players"
A3 = The cell I'm having a problem with

Sheet 2 :
A1:A5 : List of soccer plays (Ronaldo, Zidane...)

Sheet 3 :
A lot of datas in which I can possibly find my Sheet1!A1 value
```

I'd like to be able to do this :

```
If A1<>"" then Vlookup in Sheet 3 and print my value "50255".
If A1="" then diplay the list of possible values you can set for Sheet2!Soccer players (Ronaldo, Zidane...)
```

Problem : I'm able to do both things in 2 differents cells but I cannot manage to do what I want in one cell...

To sum up : I'd like to have either the result of my `Vlookup` or (if empty) a list of possible values.

What I've tried in data validation:

```
=SI($E$31<>"";RECHERCHEV($E$31;'1 - Data players'!$G:$XFD;EQUIV('2 - OD'!$E38;'1 - Data players'!$G$6:$EX$6;0);FAUX);indirect($E$38))
```

Formula in English Excel:

```
=IF($E$31<>"",VLOOKUP($E$31,'1 - Data players'!$G:$XFD,MATCH('2 - OD'!$E38,'1 - Data players'!$G$6:$EX$6,0),FALSE),INDIRECT($E$38))
```

Could you help me?

Comment: If you can do both things in 2 different cells, shouldn't the IF formula work to accomplish both within 1 cell? IF(logical_test,value_if_true,value_if_false), as the test is - IF A1 is equal or not equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put both the vlookup formula and validation into the same cell. The only problem is that if you set a value using the drop-down, it overwrites the formula. For your purposes, do you need the formula to return at a later point? If not, then the following solution may be suitable.

Note that to use validation from a different sheet, you need to first apply a range name to the list of values, then refer to the range name in the data validation.

I've set up 3 sheets as per your example. I've set "Players" as the range name for A1:A3 on Sheet2 containing the list of player names. I've then put a vlookup formula into A3:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet3!$A$1:$B$3,2,0),"")
```

[image: Formula]

Then added data validation to A3 using the List option:

```
=IF($A$1="",Players,"")
```

[image: Data Validation]

Then the drop down menu appears if I clear the value from A1:

[image: Dropdown]

Answer (score 2):

Add a `Worksheet_Change` event to the first worksheeet (per your context) e.g. `Sheet1` and then when the target cell (`A1`) changes then you can check the value and then either

- Add a data validation to `A3` with `Range("A3").Validation.Add...`, or
- Insert a formula to `A3` with whatever you need

The example below just uses a simple list and `VLOOKUP` range that you can adapt to your circumstances:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim blnChange As Boolean
    Dim strVlookupFormula As String

    On Error GoTo ExitFunction:

    'vlookup if target is not empty
    strVlookupFormula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A$1,$E$2:$F$4,2,FALSE),""no match"")"

    'was our cell changed
    blnChange = Not Application.Intersect(Target, Sheet1.Range("A1")) Is Nothing

    If blnChange Then
        'disable events as we are going to update cells
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        'is cell empty
        If IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then

            'remove anything from cell
            Sheet1.Range("A3").ClearContents

            'add data validation to cell
            With Sheet1.Range("A3").Validation

                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                    AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                    Operator:=xlBetween, _
                    Formula1:="=Sheet1!C2:C5"

                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        Else

            'remove any validation
            Sheet1.Range("A3").Validation.Delete

            'add vlookup formula to cell
            Sheet1.Range("A3").Formula = strVlookupFormula

        End If
    End If

ExitFunction:
    ' re-enable events
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Example with the data validation on empty `A1` value:

[image]

Example with the formula with non-empty `A1` value:

[image]

Comment: Wow that's a big chunk of code! Thanks Robin that's great. I'm gonna look at it tonight. To be clear, I cannot avoid VBA for what I need? Thanks. Jean

Comment: I can't think of way to do it with a formula !